# flex mobile - load image from bytearray - Error #2044: Unhandled securityError

Tags: arrays, image, sqlite, apache-flex, mobile

In a mobile application I try to load an image from a sqlite database and want to show it in a mxml image component. 
The loading of the bytearray works fine, but when I assign the bytearray to the image component I get following error.

> Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #3226: Cannot import
>   a SWF file when LoaderContext.allowCodeImport is false.

I also tried to save and load the image as a base64 string. but it does not help.

Even if I try a simple thing like this:

```
var byteArray:ByteArray =  img1.loaderInfo.bytes;
img2.source = byteArray;
```

just add the bytearray of img1 to the empty img2 - the same error occurs.

whats going wrong here?
many thanks for your help,
cheers, 
Flo

Comment: Can I see what "img2" is?  Is that an image component?

Comment: img1 and img2 are both image component: <s:Image/>

Comment: First, why are you saving an image into the database? Second, how are you loading the bytearray into the other?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it thinks you're loading swf bytes.

Try this little hack just for kicks and tell me what happens :

```
var bitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(content.width,content.height,true,0x00000000);
bitmapData.draw(loader.content, new Matrix(),null,null,null,true);
img2.source = new Bitmap( bitmapData );
```

where `loader` is your loader obviously.

Comment: ob my god! i did a really bad thing - i gave the base64 encoder following:
`img1.loaderInfo.bytes;`
after deep thinking, this is of course not the bytearray of the image! :)
    `img1.loaderInfo.loaderURL = "app:/myapp.swf"`
loaderUrl shows what it always tried to load: the bytearray of myapp.swf!
ok thanks for your help! maybe someone else is doing the same stupid thing! :)
cheers, 
florian

Comment: no problem, it was baffling me because that error shouldn't pop unless its a swf.  pretty funny.   :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mx or spark `Image`?

`mx:Image` extends `SWFLoader`, so trying to set its source directly could result in a security error because you are essentially importing code. `spark:Image` wraps a `BitmapImage`. You will likely have better luck with that.

**Edit**  I just saw your comment. I've also had security issues with loading bytearray data and setting it to the source of BitmapImage. Mine were sandbox issues due to no crossdomain.xml, but I've never used the mobile sdk.